# New install of 19c with 11g client; ORA-12560 error

Tags: oracle11g, oracle19c

On a new Windows Server 2016 PC:

- signed on as administrator
- Fresh install of 19c with default orcl database. No issues during install
- Installed full 32-bit 11g client (needed for connection to legacy app) no install issues
- added SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER = 11  to sqlnet.ora
- tnsping orcl ran and showed connection
- sqlplus /nolog
- connect / as sysadm
- returned ORA-12560 TNS Adapter: protocol adapter error

Both listener and orcl services are running (tried restarting them but still got error)
Tried setting $TNS_ADMIN and $ORACLE_HOME but error still occurs.
Tried rebooting but no change.

PATH has client oci.dll folder listed first then ORACLE HOME folder

Pulling hair out has commenced...

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Oracle database, but I had a similar problem while installing Oracle 21DB express. I kept installing and uninstalling because I could not get past the login/password. It kept giving me

"ORA-12560 TNS Adapter: protocol adapter error"

what I finally did was on my last installation, on the setup.exe, you must right click on the mouse and "run as administrator". Then everything ran perfectly. Also while researching I was told don't have more than 1 version of SQL on a machine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).